# php/mysql insert into query returns null

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling with my project as I want to read an sql file formatted in a specific way and execute queries in it. I need to check if the first query has been executed in order to continue. However the first query returns null value. Can someone help me please ? I tried mysql error but it returns nothing too. Here is the code.

```
<?php

    $inserts = file_get_contents($nom_definitif);
    $inserts = preg_replace('/--+\s.*/i', "", $inserts);
    $inserts = preg_split("/;/Si", $inserts);

    $insert = str_replace('INSERT INTO', '', $inserts[0] . " ;");
    $res_insert_etab = phpAdm_dbQuery('INSERT INTO ' . $insert);

    //this returns the name of database
    echo "db ".$phpAdm_config['dbname_etablissements']."<br>";
    //but this returns null
    echo "res_insert: ".$res_insert_etab."<br>";

    if($res_insert_etab){
        //get last inserted id
        $last_etab_id = phpAdm_dbInsertID();
        //execute create database query
        $create_query = str_replace('###_###etablissement_###_###', 'etablissement_'.$last_etab_id, $inserts[1]. " ;");     
        mysql_db_query($phpAdm_config['dbname_etablissements'],$create_query);

        echo "lastid ".$last_etab_id;
        //$inserts = preg_replace($inserts[0], "", $inserts);

        $i=0;
        foreach ($inserts as $insert) {
            // 2 premières instructions exéctuées au dessus
            if($i>1){               
                $insert = str_replace('INSERT INTO', '', $insert);
                if(strlen($insert)>strlen('INSERT INTO')){
                    $insert = str_replace('###_###etablissement_###_###', 'etablissement_'.$last_etab_id, $insert. " ;");
                    $res_insertion = phpAdm_dbQuery('INSERT INTO ' . $insert);
                    echo "res".$res_insertion." <br>";
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: echo your query and check it in db

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The queries were correct the problem came from the sql file but it's weird that it didn't prompt any  error as there was an extra column in the sql file insert query. Now I get the entry in the db but I get 0 as last inserted id.